# Vue didn't show date Value

Tags: date, vue.js, mongoose

I am trying to get and modify a date value, I get the date value from mongoose, I correctly get the value, and I can modify it correctly, but moongoose give me the date in this format :

> YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z,

So I want to change the display value with an Italian format, like: DD/MM/YYYY.
I have try with this:

```
<template>
    <div class="col">
        <span> Date </span>
        <input
         :value="birth" v-on:input="birth = $event.target.value" type="date" />
        </div>
</template>

    <script>
    import DataService from '@/services/DataService'
    import ClickToEdit from '@/components/ClickToEdit'
    import moment from 'moment'
    export default {
      name: 'Options',
      data: function() {
        return {
         birth: '',
        }
      },
      methods: {
        async getAllInfo() {
          var userInfo = await DataService.getInfoFromSomeWhere({
          })
        this.birth = this.frontEndDateFormat(userInfo.data.user[0].birth)
        },
        frontEndDateFormat: function(date) {
        return moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
       }
      },
      mounted() {
      this.getAllInfo()
     }
    }
    </script>
```

The date was correctly changed, but the vue page didn't display the date value, and I think is because the default input value display the date in this way :

> gg/mm/aaaa

I have already try to change the frontEndDateFormat method with gg/mm/aaaa instead of DD/MM/YYYY, but If I do this I have a strange value in input, like gg/00/amamamama ( I think the problem is related to moment).

So I tried to use :

```
<input :value="birth" v-on:input="birth = $event.target.value" type="date" v-model="date" />
```

But If I get an error:

> :value="birth" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the
>   latter already expands to a value binding internally

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: The question doesn't indicate how you tried to display the value. Where does `getAllInfo()` get called?

Comment: @tony19 sorry I forgot, now I update the post, can you help me?